# Tkinter traceback variable not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have a function named **to1 which take input from entry widget** searches for it in a file displays the buttons with text of all similar lines. now **get_button_text1 function take the button id and extract the text** of a particular button and stores it in a variable called **btn_text**. Now issue is when I call this global variable **btn_text** in a new function find1 it gives a error **btn_text** no defined.
I am attaching the code and traceback error respectively.

```
def get_button_text1(button_id):
    global btn_text
    """Function to retrieve text of a button with a given identifier"""
    # print(ubtn)
    btn_text = ubtn1[button_id]['text']
    # dataIO.valueentry(btn_text, None, None, None)
    # top1.destroy()
    # print(btn_text)

    return btn_text


# from home import *
def to1():
    global top1
    top1 = Toplevel()
    string_list = []  # empty list to store the strings
    c = desentry1.get()
    a = str(c)
    # print(a)
    b = ""
    if a.startswith("UC") or a.startswith("uc") or a.startswith("nibp"):
        a = a.upper()
    else:
        a = a.capitalize()
    b = a
    # print(b)
    search_words = b.split()
    i = 0
    with open("materialcode.txt", "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    # key = k.upper()

    for line in lines:
        # if word in key:

        for word in search_words:
            if word in line:
                global buttons
                # print(line)
                buttons = {}

                string_name = f"string1_{i + 1}"  # create a variable name with a unique number
                string_value = f"{line}"  # create the string value
                locals()[string_name] = string_value  # dynamically create the variable and assign the string value
                string_list.append(locals()[string_name])  # add the variable to the list
                button_text = locals()[f"string1_{i + 1}"]  # create the text for the button
                button = ttk.Button(top1, text=button_text, command=lambda button_id=i: get_button_text1(
                    button_id))  # create the button with the text
                button.pack()  # add the button to the GUI
                buttons[i] = button
                # print(button)
                ubtn1.update(buttons)
                i += 1
                break
    # print(string_list)
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------funx
def find1():
    to1()
    desentry1.delete(0,END)
    # ov1=StringVar()
    ov1=btn_text
    print(ov1)
    desentry1.insert(0,ov1)
```

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Dekstop Folder\pycharm\Uni-Card\sepr.py", line 92, in find1
    ov1=btn_text
        ^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'btn_text' is not defined
```

I want my entry widget text to be changed to what is stored in **btn_text** variable.

Comment: The variable `btn_text` is only created when you first run the `get_button_text1` function. You never actually run this function, you only assign it as command to your button. So the variable is not yet created, but you already try to use it in the `find1` function.

Comment: Also next time try to post a minimal reproducible example. Your code is not running on its own.

Comment: @steTATO ok ill look into it and i cannot put the whole code here its around 400-500 line and doing so will result in no one understanding it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimal reproducible example for your problem.
It works out of the box, it only contains the parts that are necessary.

```
import tkinter as tk


def print_text(x):
    print(btn_strings[x])


def to1():
    global btn_strings

    btn_strings = []  # empty list to store the strings
    b = 'hello world'
    search_words = b.split()

    with open("search_text.txt", "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()

    i = 0
    for line in lines:
        for word in search_words:
            if word in line:
                print('found', word)
                btn_strings.append(word)
                button = tk.Button(root, text=word, command=lambda v=i: print_text(v))
                button.pack()
                i += 1
                break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    to1()
    root.mainloop()
```

My `search_text.txt` file contains the following lines:

```
stackoverflow
hello
world
spam
text
python
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return from `to1()` only when you have clicked one of the buttons, so you need to make the toplevel window like a modal dialog. Then you need to close the toplevel window inside `get_button_text1()`.

Below is the modified `get_button_text1()` and `to1()`:

```py
def get_button_text1(button_id):
    global btn_text
    btn_text = ubtn1[button_id]['text']
    # close the toplevel
    top1.destroy()
    return btn_text


def to1():
    global top1
    top1 = Toplevel()
    string_list = []  # empty list to store the strings
    c = desentry1.get()
    a = str(c)
    # print(a)
    b = ""
    if a.startswith("UC") or a.startswith("uc") or a.startswith("nibp"):
        a = a.upper()
    else:
        a = a.capitalize()
    b = a
    # print(b)
    search_words = b.split()
    i = 0
    with open("materialcode.txt", "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    # key = k.upper()

    for line in lines:
        # if word in key:

        for word in search_words:
            if word in line:
                global buttons
                # print(line)
                buttons = {}

                string_name = f"string1_{i + 1}"  # create a variable name with a unique number
                string_value = f"{line}"  # create the string value
                locals()[string_name] = string_value  # dynamically create the variable and assign the string value
                string_list.append(locals()[string_name])  # add the variable to the list
                button_text = locals()[f"string1_{i + 1}"]  # create the text for the button
                button = ttk.Button(top1, text=button_text, command=lambda button_id=i: get_button_text1(
                    button_id))  # create the button with the text
                button.pack()  # add the button to the GUI
                buttons[i] = button
                # print(button)
                ubtn1.update(buttons)
                i += 1
                break
    # print(string_list)

    # make this toplevel like a dialog
    top1.grab_set()
    top1.wait_window()
```

Comment: Thanks brother , it helped . i would have upvoted this but i lacked reputation 